# Is there a memo flag for transfer transaction in polkadot?

Tags: polkadot

Like cosmos or beacon chain, can we attach a memo in polkadot which describes the transaction in better way?
For example while transferring dot can we attach a string like field which describes the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

A memo cannot be directly passed into the transfer function. Otherwise how would it look like for other transactions, such as NFT transfers, identity update ...etc? Each transaction would need to be changed to also accept a memo parameter.

Instead, multiple calls can batch; the `transfer` and a `System::remark` (the memo).
Though I dont know if wallets have nice UI support for sending these. It is definitely possible to do on PolkadotJS.
Some wallets/signers also offer to just store a local memo for the transaction that will never be published to the chain. Polkadot Vault does this.

[image: Extrinsic in PJs]